# Datatooltk doesn't show text in greek

Tags: xetex, greek, datatool

I would like to create a database of exercises using the `datatooltk` program along with the `datatool` package. My text is in greek and this is a snapshot of two exercises written within `datatooltk` in a `math.dbtex` :
[image]

Whenever I complile using `xelatex` the following mwe, greek text doesn't show. With `pdflatex` on the other hand everything works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Minion Pro Bold}]{Minion Pro}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{datatool}

\newbool{showanswers}
\booltrue{showanswers}

\DTLloaddbtex{\problemDB}{math.dbtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}\bfseries\Large
Assignment~1
\end{center}

\begin{enumerate}
\DTLforeach*{\problemDB}
 {\Label=Label,\Question=Question}%
 {%
   \item \Question
 }
\end{enumerate}

\ifbool{showanswers}
{%
 \section{Solutions}

\begin{enumerate}
\DTLforeach*{\problemDB}
 {\Label=Label,\Answer=Answer}%
 {%
   \item \Answer
 }
\end{enumerate}

}{}\vspace{3cm}
\begin{center}
{\Large Κείμενο} % Normally written greek text
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

A sample output looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can do show it can support the greek language with `xelatex`?

Comment: Try using a font which supports Greek? Your question is pretty meaningless as it stands since we have no idea what is in the `.dbtex` file which presumably contains the code causing you problems. However, if you look at the console output or the log, it probably tells you what the problem is anyway.

Comment: But note that the Greek in maths mode is not the same as the Greek text supported by `xgreek`. It is impossible to tell without the code, but aren't your equations using maths mode rather than text mode? Or is the Greek in `\text{}` or something? Or is the question text to start with? I can't tell anything from the image - it could be anything.

Comment: My questions written inside `datatooltk` contain plain greek text and math. These two sample exercises talk about solving equations. Both say "Solve the equation". I can't imagine what's causing the problem since the same greek text shows well when compiled with `pdflatex`. The `math.dbtex` file contains 3 columns which are "Label", "Question" and "Answer". Text written with the same font outside `math.dbtex` shows well. (Κείμενο means "Text").

Comment: `datatooltk` should generate UTF-8 files. If you view the `.dbtex` file in a text editor with the encoding set to UTF-8 does the text show correctly? (The cell contents should follow instances of `\db@row@id@w` within the `.dbtex` file.)

Comment: @ Nicola Talbot. I opened the `dbtex` file in a text editor and greek text shows well. I even saved a copy with UTF-8 encoding just to be sure.

Comment: The point is: nobody but you can reproduce the issue. Don't describe the file - provide a minimal version so people can actually try your code. Right now, the code we've got is pretty much pointless unless it contains some glaring error because nobody but you can use it. Screen shots are not useful when the issue is code causing problems.

Comment: I know you are right. But the thing is I can not think of anything else than what I said above. When I replace greek text with english or when I use `pdflatex` instead of `xetex`everything copliles fine. I wish I could be more helpful but I dont know where to look for the error.